# How to explode a texarea value in php?

Tags: php, explode

I am getting post value from a textarea like this:

```
11223344
55667788
99001122
33445566
77889900
```

I need to form it like

```
Array
(
    [0] => 11223344
    [1] => 55667788
    [2] => 99001122
    [3] => 33445566
    [4] => 11223344
    [5] => 77889900
)
```

using `explode()` function in php. how it possible?
I have already used `explode('\n\r', $datas)`.
thanks

Comment: Try using `\r\n` or just `\n`

Comment: `'\n\r'` is single quotes won't become a newline and carriage return. Also it's typically present in the exact opposite order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use double quotes instead of single ones:

```
print_r( explode("\n", $datas) );
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
preg_split("/\s+/", "11223344 55667788 99001122 33445566 77889900");
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try Next :**

```
print_r(preg_split('/\r\n|[\r\n]/', $_POST['thetextarea']));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Double Quotes:

Try `"\n\r"` (double quotes) or just `"\n"`

When you use `'\n\r'` it means search for `\n\r` and explode about it. It won't search for newline or carriage return. When you use double quotes, it would parse for newline or carriage return.